# Why isn't the automatic "low quality post" flag automatically dismissed when the post is edited?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, automatic-flags

When a user flag a post as very low quality, and the post is then edited, the flag is automatically declined as disputed.

Why isn't the same done for the automatic low quality flag?
If the edit done from a user cannot be interpreted as meaning the flag was not (completely) correct, then the flag should be dismissed when a moderator edits the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, both types of flags are dismissed as "helpful" when a flagged post is edited. This change was made on July 23rd, 2013.

While I consider the current dismissal logic to be appropriate, [we may wish to revisit some of the other behaviors associated with this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236883/community-downvotes-posts-that-were-just-fixed) in the future.