# Community should not autodownvote "low quality" autoflags cleared by edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, low-quality-posts, community-user

Consider:

1. User posts an answer.
2. Community autoflags it as "low quality (auto)." (This is frequently a false positive.)
3. User edits answer after 5-minute grace period. (Or perhaps someone else edits the answer.)
4. Community sees the edit and obediently marks the "low quality (auto)" flag as helpful.
5. Community applies an automatic downvote to the post, triggered by said edit.

Users are, therefore, **penalized for improving their answers.** This is wrong, wrong, wrong.

If a user posts an answer which gets autoflagged and someone else edits the answer to fix a typo, it absolutely should not come with a downvote. This makes no sense at all.

Possible solutions, in increasing order of preference:

- Implement [something like this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266436/180276), where the downvote is revoked if the post is later upvoted (this is what happens with "very low quality" flags, but not "low quality (auto)" flags). This is... not ideal, since the downvote shouldn't be there in the first place.
- Do not apply an autodownvote if the flag was cleared by an edit. This is also not perfect, as it's an ugly special case and requires extra complexity. Which leads to...
- **Do not clear any type of flag on edits.** This doesn't really make any sense in the first place. Edits are not necessarily guaranteed to improve a post; indeed, sometimes edits make a post *worse*. And using edits as a trigger to clear flags can be actively harmful, too, because perhaps the edit did not remove the content that the answer was flagged for, but the auto-flag-clearing prevents a moderator from seeing it.
- **Do not apply automatic downvotes when "low quality (auto)" flags are marked helpful.** In theory, it's a good idea, but I often reflexively mark any Community ♦ flag as helpful just because it's less clicks and it doesn't make a difference... except in this case. It's hidden, confusing behavior, and I can't count how many times I've accidentally "downvoted" perfectly valid answers (indeed, it took me quite a while to finally catch on to what was happening). This problem is exacerbated by the fact that this specific flag has a very high false positive rate (on the sites I moderate, at any rate).
- Both of the above (don't clear flags on edits, *and* don't autodownvote when flags are cleared as helpful, since neither are at all intuitive).

Comment: "The system will now revoke the automatic downvote if, after the flag is marked Helpful, the post later gets an upvote. 

Remember, the automatic downvote essentially exists because folks use this flag in cases where *they should be downvoting*. As such, it serves an important role... But should still be considered weak compared to actually downvoting the post in cases where there is conflicting information..." ([Community downvotes posts that were just fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266436/165773))

Comment: @gnat I'm talking about the "low quality (auto)" automatic system flag (as I mentioned repeatedly in my question), **not** the "very low quality" flag.

Comment: I think same reasoning should apply to auto-flags: upvote to post forces Community user revoke downvote. If this doesn't happen, I would say that's a design mistake and linked post explains why the other way is correct

Comment: Wait, auto VLQ flags are still a thing? I haven't seen one in.. over a year?

Comment: @ɥʇǝS We get them nearly daily on PPCG (last one was *Low answer quality score [80]* just yesterday, in fact).

Comment: @Doorknob I'm looking at this request - are you seeing this more on PPCG or Puzzling? Asking because you're a mod on both.

Comment: @bluefeet You mean the undesirable behavior? It happens on both. Or do you mean auto low quality flags in general? They're very common on both sites as well (probably just because short answers are common due to how Puzzling and PPCG work).

Comment: @Doorknob Both. I'm going to pull some numbers on it so I wanted to know where to look initially. :)

Comment: Holy ****. Is this why I see downvotes on crappy answers almost immediately after I edit them? I kept thinking it might be coincidence, but it's happened so often...

Answer (score 32):

## Update: August 15, 2019

[The system no longer automatically downvotes posts as a result of automatic flags anymore.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330415/377214)

## Update: August 31, 2017

Internally, we discussed several ways to implement this, but in the end we made them [work the same as normal VLQ flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266436/164200). That means, if the flag was marked helpful, but later receives an upvote the automatic downvote is revoked. This is available as of the latest build. Thanks to the devs for implementing this change, and making the behavior the same across both VLQ flag types.

I agree that this probably shouldn't happen, if someone edits a post to improve it, punishing the OP after a post was edited isn't the best experience.

I was curious how often this happens so I pulled some numbers for the last 365 days. Stack Overflow is excluded because it doesn't get low quality (auto) flags, the data below is for all non-meta sites that had at least one helpful flag:

| Total Flags | Total Helpful | Total Helpful By Edit | Pct Validated By Edit | Site Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5252 | 4582 | 441 | 9.62 | Super User |
| 1678 | 1229 | 91 | 7.40 | Server Fault |
| 18 | 18 | 0 | 0.00 | Stack Apps |
| 898 | 721 | 42 | 5.83 | Cooking |
| 855 | 801 | 52 | 6.49 | Home Improvement |
| 407 | 369 | 34 | 9.21 | Game Developers |
| 5331 | 4955 | 377 | 7.61 | Gaming |
| 923 | 884 | 56 | 6.33 | GIS |
| 349 | 280 | 36 | 12.86 | Mathematics |
| 363 | 348 | 25 | 7.18 | Photography |
| 701 | 658 | 44 | 6.69 | Statistical Analysis |
| 1221 | 1195 | 91 | 7.62 | Web Apps |
| 320 | 287 | 23 | 8.01 | Webmasters |
| 4548 | 4086 | 205 | 5.02 | Apple |
| 25 | 24 | 2 | 8.33 | Theoretical Computer Science |
| 3541 | 2664 | 407 | 15.28 | English Language and Usage |
| 262 | 258 | 5 | 1.94 | Personal Finance and Money |
| 172 | 157 | 16 | 10.19 | Role-playing Games |
| 879 | 796 | 135 | 16.96 | TeX - LaTeX |
| 393 | 314 | 40 | 12.74 | Ubuntu |
| 2101 | 1735 | 444 | 25.59 | Unix and Linux |
| 1227 | 1144 | 111 | 9.70 | WordPress |
| 218 | 211 | 17 | 8.06 | Bicycles |
| 136 | 135 | 9 | 6.67 | Programmers |
| 4766 | 4595 | 272 | 5.92 | Android Enthusiasts |
| 125 | 109 | 9 | 8.26 | Board and Card Games |
| 1287 | 1197 | 81 | 6.77 | Physics |
| 50 | 37 | 3 | 8.11 | Homebrew |
| 545 | 532 | 34 | 6.39 | IT Security |
| 96 | 89 | 5 | 5.62 | Writers |
| 1244 | 1218 | 78 | 6.40 | Electronics and Robotics |
| 799 | 640 | 43 | 6.72 | Graphic Design |
| 719 | 645 | 77 | 11.94 | Database Administrators |
| 789 | 659 | 89 | 13.51 | Science Fiction |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.00 | Area 51 Discussions |
| 341 | 331 | 28 | 8.46 | Code Review |
| 229 | 166 | 78 | 46.99 | Code Golf |
| 76 | 68 | 8 | 11.76 | Quantitative Finance |
| 28 | 26 | 0 | 0.00 | Project Management |
| 197 | 197 | 3 | 1.52 | Skeptics |
| 849 | 735 | 75 | 10.20 | Drupal Answers |
| 103 | 101 | 10 | 9.90 | Fitness and Nutrition |
| 426 | 385 | 26 | 6.75 | Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair |
| 173 | 173 | 3 | 1.73 | Parenting |
| 1063 | 959 | 62 | 6.47 | SharePoint |
| 240 | 217 | 9 | 4.15 | Musical Practice and Performance |
| 118 | 112 | 17 | 15.18 | Software Quality Assurance and Testing |
| 148 | 128 | 22 | 17.19 | Jewish Life and Learning |
| 74 | 73 | 2 | 2.74 | Astronomy |
| 163 | 126 | 30 | 23.81 | German Language and Usage |
| 108 | 63 | 11 | 17.46 | Japanese Language and Usage |
| 136 | 127 | 12 | 9.45 | Gardening and Landscaping |
| 97 | 96 | 9 | 9.38 | Philosophy |
| 48 | 46 | 4 | 8.70 | Personal Productivity |
| 633 | 584 | 28 | 4.79 | Travel |
| 88 | 86 | 6 | 6.98 | Cryptography |
| 107 | 107 | 14 | 13.08 | Signal Processing |
| 136 | 100 | 22 | 22.00 | French Language and Usage |
| 308 | 308 | 12 | 3.90 | Christianity |
| 255 | 249 | 13 | 5.22 | Bitcoin |
| 54 | 53 | 3 | 5.66 | Linguistics |
| 120 | 120 | 2 | 1.67 | Biblical Hermeneutics |
| 32 | 31 | 4 | 12.90 | Economics |
| 166 | 159 | 7 | 4.40 | History |
| 110 | 95 | 8 | 8.42 | LEGO® |
| 151 | 142 | 22 | 15.49 | Spanish Language and Usage |
| 42 | 38 | 2 | 5.26 | Computational Science |
| 909 | 889 | 66 | 7.42 | Movies |
| 235 | 123 | 16 | 13.01 | Chinese Language and Usage |
| 222 | 220 | 7 | 3.18 | Biology |
| 40 | 38 | 4 | 10.53 | Poker |
| 165 | 149 | 23 | 15.44 | Mathematica |
| 55 | 54 | 2 | 3.70 | Cognitive Sciences |
| 67 | 59 | 3 | 5.08 | The Great Outdoors |
| 32 | 32 | 0 | 0.00 | Martial Arts |
| 136 | 135 | 5 | 3.70 | Sports |
| 269 | 255 | 15 | 5.88 | Academia |
| 132 | 122 | 13 | 10.66 | Computer Science |
| 121 | 119 | 7 | 5.88 | The Workplace |
| 551 | 524 | 12 | 2.29 | Windows Phone |
| 547 | 538 | 34 | 6.32 | Chemistry |
| 132 | 108 | 19 | 17.59 | Chess |
| 520 | 422 | 23 | 5.45 | Raspberry Pi |
| 104 | 77 | 5 | 6.49 | Russian Language and Usage |
| 363 | 361 | 11 | 3.05 | Islam |
| 770 | 648 | 56 | 8.64 | Salesforce |
| 55 | 49 | 0 | 0.00 | Patents |
| 236 | 231 | 15 | 6.49 | User Experience |
| 28 | 28 | 4 | 14.29 | Genealogy and Family History |
| 41 | 41 | 0 | 0.00 | Robotics |
| 68 | 63 | 3 | 4.76 | ExpressionEngine |
| 48 | 46 | 2 | 4.35 | Politics |
| 97 | 86 | 5 | 5.81 | Audio-Video Production |
| 731 | 659 | 81 | 12.29 | Anime and Manga |
| 1255 | 1067 | 80 | 7.50 | Magento |
| 793 | 677 | 81 | 11.96 | English Language Learners |
| 22 | 22 | 0 | 0.00 | Sustainable Living |
| 17 | 17 | 1 | 5.88 | Tridion Stack Exchange |
| 51 | 41 | 6 | 14.63 | Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange |
| 262 | 210 | 23 | 10.95 | Arduino Stack Exchange |
| 214 | 198 | 6 | 3.03 | Network Engineering Stack Exchange |
| 42 | 40 | 4 | 10.00 | Open Data Stack Exchange |
| 22 | 22 | 2 | 9.09 | Freelancing Stack Exchange |
| 384 | 353 | 30 | 8.50 | Blender Stack Exchange |
| 193 | 178 | 8 | 4.49 | MathOverflow |
| 91 | 90 | 4 | 4.44 | Space Exploration Stack Exchange |
| 112 | 104 | 5 | 4.81 | Sound Design Stack Exchange |
| 124 | 117 | 5 | 4.27 | Tor Stack Exchange |
| 139 | 138 | 2 | 1.45 | Pets Stack Exchange |
| 23 | 19 | 0 | 0.00 | Amateur Radio Stack Exchange |
| 30 | 26 | 3 | 11.54 | Italian Language Stack Exchange |
| 872 | 750 | 102 | 13.60 | Stack Overflow em Português |
| 197 | 181 | 9 | 4.97 | Aviation Stack Exchange |
| 32 | 31 | 2 | 6.45 | Ebooks Stack Exchange |
| 43 | 40 | 0 | 0.00 | Beer Stack Exchange |
| 189 | 186 | 15 | 8.06 | Software Recommendations Stack Exchange |
| 68 | 65 | 2 | 3.08 | Expatriates Stack Exchange |
| 20 | 16 | 0 | 0.00 | Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange |
| 49 | 47 | 1 | 2.13 | Earth Science Stack Exchange |
| 127 | 119 | 13 | 10.92 | Joomla Stack Exchange |
| 41 | 40 | 4 | 10.00 | Data Science Stack Exchange |
| 435 | 366 | 107 | 29.23 | Puzzling Stack Exchange |
| 54 | 43 | 5 | 11.63 | Craft CMS Stack Exchange |
| 59 | 57 | 11 | 19.30 | Buddhism Stack Exchange |
| 206 | 204 | 5 | 2.45 | Hinduism Stack Exchange |
| 6 | 6 | 0 | 0.00 | Moderators Stack Exchange |
| 31 | 28 | 2 | 7.14 | Startups Stack Exchange |
| 207 | 201 | 15 | 7.46 | Worldbuilding Stack Exchange |
| 256 | 165 | 24 | 14.55 | スタック・オーバーフロー |
| 47 | 37 | 10 | 27.03 | Emacs Stack Exchange |
| 20 | 19 | 1 | 5.26 | History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange |
| 239 | 222 | 23 | 10.36 | Lifehacks Stack Exchange |
| 55 | 52 | 5 | 9.62 | Engineering Stack Exchange |
| 27 | 22 | 4 | 18.18 | Coffee Stack Exchange |
| 25 | 20 | 4 | 20.00 | Vi and Vim Stack Exchange |
| 62 | 55 | 8 | 14.55 | Music Fans Stack Exchange |
| 32 | 24 | 3 | 12.50 | Woodworking Stack Exchange |
| 66 | 50 | 4 | 8.00 | CiviCRM Stack Exchange |
| 36 | 36 | 0 | 0.00 | Health Stack Exchange |
| 2659 | 1844 | 602 | 32.65 | Stack Overflow на русском |
| 453 | 249 | 139 | 55.82 | Русский язык |
| 11 | 10 | 0 | 0.00 | Mythology Stack Exchange |
| 32 | 31 | 0 | 0.00 | Law Stack Exchange |
| 6 | 6 | 0 | 0.00 | Open Source Stack Exchange |
| 165 | 154 | 22 | 14.29 | elementary OS Stack Exchange |
| 29 | 23 | 7 | 30.43 | Portuguese Language Stack Exchange |
| 3 | 2 | 0 | 0.00 | Computer Graphics Stack Exchange |
| 10 | 10 | 3 | 30.00 | Hardware Recommendations Stack Exchange |
| 47 | 44 | 13 | 29.55 | Stack Overflow en español |

Besides the Russian Language site, Code Golf has one of the highest percentages so I understand why you noticed this.

I'm answering because I'm looking at it and will try to figure out the best way this should be implemented. To be clear, any change will only impact the auto flag, it will not impact VLQ flags placed by users because those have been seen by a human and that means a higher signal of a problem.

Comment: `it will not impact VLQ flags placed by users because those have been seen by a human and that means a higher signal of a problem.`  That sounds like the downvote should be added immediately, like spam flags -- not like the user should be punished when they *fix* that problem.

Comment: Stack Overflow на русском has the biggest impact on that, seems legit...

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Perhaps Cyrillic isn't being treated as text by LQ(a) bot.