# Add link to timeline view

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, timeline

The question "[Add a link to the timeline of a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post)" was asked in 2012, and the status was initially declined. Since then the timeline feature has evolved and become more useful, and 2015 the status was changed to deferred.

Can we revisit this and get a permanent link to the timeline on every post? It is quite a pain to have to manually change the URL anytime you want to use it. This request seemed to be well received initially, and as Shog9 said in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180594/260884), it has become much more useful since this feature was first proposed. Sha Wiz Dow Ard even proposed a [great solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126493/260884) which doesn't add any new text to the posts.

Comment: Your browser doesn't support userscripts?

Comment: @rene I can't say it's something I've ever tried or would know how to use, though I could probably figure it out. However, I think this is a feature that would be useful to *everyone* and shouldn't be limited to those with the technical know-how to modify their browser. Not all SE sites are technically oriented.

Comment: It is not declined, it's deferred (Almost the same, but not totally the same). No point asking for this again. While I'm all for this feature, I am also against posting duplicates on purpose, sorry.

Comment: That said, if you have any new idea or new info, feel free to add new answer on the original request or edit it with new info, that will also bump it to the front page.

Comment: I've had this on the list for a good long while. We'll get to it, eventually.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No worries, I wasn't exactly sure of the protocol for repeat requests of older posts that were never really resolved. I also wasn't sure if deferred meant "we'll make a decision on this later" or "we'll implement this, but not right now".

Comment: Well, Shog said it in his answer. Deferred means "we are not rejecting it, just not doing it in the near future, and might do that in the not-so-near future". For years I was also sure it means "death sentence" to the request, but with the new DAG team, they started digging out such old requests and actually do them. (Think the latest is [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276269/community-should-not-autodownvote-low-quality-autoflags-cleared-by-edits).)