# When does Community ♦ cast votes?

Tags: support, voting, down-votes, up-votes

I recently noticed on Ask Ubuntu that Community ♦ casts upvotes and downvotes.  I read in [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236883/community-downvotes-posts-that-were-just-fixed) that Community can cast downvotes in some cases, but I haven't found any information on upvotes.  Here's a screenshot from Community's profile on AU:

[image]

I checked on a few other sites; here is mechanics.stackexchange's Community profile:

[image]

And Stack Overflows:

[image]

And last but not least, IoT beta:

[image]

So my question is, **under what situations can Community vote on posts?**