# Why is there no "duplicate answer" comment on late answer reviews?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, duplicate-answers, late-answers

When reviewing Late Answers, the `Delete` option description reads

> Answer does not address the question, *is a duplicate*, or cannot be improved.
> <sup>emphasis added</sup>

as shown here:
[image: Screen cap of "Actions" dialog for late answer review]

However, when I select that and hit `Submit`, the dialog box doesn't give me any default text for "This is a duplicate of one or more existing answers", as seen here:
[image: Screen shot of "add comment for author" dialog box]

Why is this not a canned option and can we get it added?

I end up having to type something up by hand each time, because I feel that it's important that a new person understand why his answer is about to disappear.

*As a side note, the last option explicitly excludes spam. There should be a "This answer is spam" option to speed up deleting those. Yes, I do flag 'em as spam, but it seems there should be a comment, more for other readers than the OP who will probably never be back to read the comments and doesn't care. Different question, I know, but I thought I'd throw it in... :D*

Comment: If it's a duplicate answer, then you should be specifying at least one answer which it duplicates. This can not be easily automated without a UI that allows you to pick or specify the answer which this one duplicates. In other words, just a canned, static comment isn't sufficient. I assume that the company decided that providing such a UI was too much work for the relative benefit. Given that a static, canned comment isn't sufficient, one isn't provided.

Comment: Speaking of your side note, spam answers [should not be reviewed as Recommend Deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356132/377214).